# SQL GROUP BY, adding a column from another table works but produces inaccurate information

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

so here was my original query:

```
SELECT Batting.playerID, SUM(G) as 'G', SUM(AB) as 'AB', SUM(R) as 'R', SUM(H) as 'H', SUM(Doub) as '2B',  SUM(Trip) as '3B', 
                         SUM(HR) as 'HR', SUM(RBI) as 'RBI', SUM(SB) as 'SB', SUM(CS) as 'CS', SUM(BB) as 'BB', 
                         SUM(SO) as 'SO', SUM(IBB) as 'IBB', SUM(HBP) as 'HBP', SUM(SH) as 'SH', SUM(SF) as 'SF', SUM(GIDP) as 'GIDP', 
                         Master.nameLast, Master.nameFirst, 
    FROM Batting
        JOIN Master ON Batting.playerID = Master.playerID

WHERE Master.nameLast LIKE @lastname + '%' 
GROUP BY Batting.playerID, Master.nameLast, Master.nameFirst
```

here is my new query:

```
SELECT Batting.playerID, SUM(G) as 'G', SUM(AB) as 'AB', SUM(R) as 'R', SUM(H) as 'H', SUM(Doub) as '2B',  SUM(Trip) as '3B', 
                         SUM(HR) as 'HR', SUM(RBI) as 'RBI', SUM(SB) as 'SB', SUM(CS) as 'CS', SUM(BB) as 'BB', 
                         SUM(SO) as 'SO', SUM(IBB) as 'IBB', SUM(HBP) as 'HBP', SUM(SH) as 'SH', SUM(SF) as 'SF', SUM(GIDP) as 'GIDP', 
                         Master.nameLast, Master.nameFirst, Fielding.POS
    FROM Batting
        JOIN Master ON Batting.playerID = Master.playerID
        JOIN Fielding ON Master.playerID = Fielding.playerID
WHERE Master.nameLast LIKE @lastname + '%' 
AND Fielding.POS IN ('C', '1B','2B','3B', 'SS', 'LF', 'RF', 'CF', 'OF', 'DH')
GROUP BY Batting.playerID, Master.nameLast, Master.nameFirst, Fielding.POS
```

All i am doing is adding the pos column from the fielding table.  now i had to sum all those columns on the batting table to get totals.  some results have multiple POS's on the fielding table that relate to the sums,  ie, someone has 50 games at one pos, another 50 at another pos.  my query works, but the numbers being returned are getting multiplied a few times along the way (are a lot larger in the second query than the first) and i am getting multiple records based on the pos, i just want one.  any thoughts?  I tried a left outer join, but that didnt do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proble is that 1 record in the `Master` table can have multiple records in the `Fielding` table, which will cause the query to return each record in the `Batting` table multiple times.
If you need data from the `Fielding` table, you will need to limit it to a single record per playerID.

Comment: ok, so the batting table has a break down of baseball stats of players based on each year.  what i am returning is their career stats, hence all the sums.  the fielding table has a break down of fielding stats based on each year.  i just want to show all the positions that a player played at.  im thinking a seperate query could be easier, at least i could do that, but there has to be a way to do it here

Comment: OK, I want to break this down a little. Bob only every played 1 game, in which he scored 3 runs. During that game he played both SS and 2nd Base.
What would you like to see in this query for Bob?

Comment: well lets say that happened in 2010.  then in 2011, something similar happened.

the batting table ould show two different years of bob, with the at bats, hits, runs etc. I sum those fields, to get his career stats, so 2010 and 2011 are summed together.

the fielding table would show the position, and how many innings he played at those positions in each year.  but i dont care at all about the innings.  i jsut want to know what positions bob played at any time during his career

Comment: I understand what would be in the tables. My question was "what do you want the result of this query to look like?" And please just focus on one season for bob, with one game, 3 runs and 2 field positions.
Based on that, do you expect one record or two in the results?
What should the output of that query look like?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do 2 separate queries and merge with a UNION ALL to avoid the row multiplication.

- One of `Batting JOIN Master`
- The other on `Fielding JOIN Master`